# How can I provide a bloc for only two pages of application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

in my application there are a couple of pages. two pages need to use one bloc.
I use namedRoutes for navigating between pages and the `BlocProvider` is on the top of app widget so it is provided for all pages of application but I only want to provide it for two pages so that when I navigate to one of two pages a new instance of bloc is created and when I leave both pages the bloc is disposed...
what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very similar question [was asked](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/74) some time ago in the bloc library GitHub issues.

That's what Felix, bloc's creator wrote:

> (...) You have 3 options though:
>
> - wrap your `MaterialApp` with a `BlocProvider` for global access
> - use named routes and setup the `BlocProvider` to be scoped for the named route
> - pass the bloc via constructor into the new page and then use `BlocProvider` to make it available in the remaining subtree
> - use your another DI library to provide the blocs
>
> Imo it’s not a big deal to pass the bloc via constructor into the new page and then provide it again (...)

- https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/74#issuecomment-497308365